# ExtJS 4: Properly set waitMsgTarget using MVC pattern

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have extjs 4.0 controller:

```js
Ext.define('KS.controller.DailyReport', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

views: ['report.Daily'],


init: function() {
    this.control({
        'dailyReport button[action=send]': {
            click: this.sendDailyReport
        }
    });
},

sendDailyReport: function(button) {
    var win = button.up('window');

    form = win.down('form');
    form.getForm().waitMsgTarget = form.getEl();
    form.getForm().waitMsg = 'Sending...';
    if (form.getForm().isValid()) { // make sure the form contains valid data before submitting
        form.submit({
            success: function(form, action) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
            },
            failure: function(form, action) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
            }
        });
    } else { // display error alert if the data is invalid
        Ext.Msg.alert('Invalid Data', 'Correct them!')
    }
}
});
```

and extjs view:

```js
Ext.define('KS.view.report.Daily', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.dailyReport',

title: 'Daily report',
layout: 'fit',
autoShow: true,
initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [{
        waitMsgTarget: true,
        xtype: 'form',
        url: 'dailyReport.php',
        layout: 'fit',
        waitMsgTarget: true,
        waitMsg: 'Sending...',
        items: [{
            margin: 10,
            xtype: 'datefield',
            name: 'reportDate',
            fieldLabel: 'Report for:',
            format: 'd.m.Y.',
            altFormats: 'd.m.Y|d,m,Y|m/d/Y',
            value: '12.12.2011',
            disabledDays: [0]
        }]
    }];

    this.buttons = [{
        text: 'Send',
        action: 'send'
    },
    {
        text: 'Cancel',
        scope: this,
        handler: this.close
    }];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

As you can see I tried to set waitMsgTarget and waitMsg in both places but it is not appearing when I click Send button.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really just misusing `waitMsg` in the following ways:

1. `waitMsg` is not a config option of `Ext.form.Basic` OR `Ext.form.Panel`. The `waitMsg` must be set within your `Ext.form.action.Submit`. This is why setting it in the view will never work.
2. In your controller you are doing the same thing and setting the `waitMsg` as if it were a property of `Ext.form.Basic`.

The fix is simple. Set `waitMsg` in your `Ext.form.action.Submit`. So, just change the line(s) within `form.submit()` to something like:

```
form.submit({
    waitMsg: 'Sending...',
    success: function(form, action) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
        },
    //..... your other stuff here
});
```

and remove these lines from the controller:

```
form.getForm().waitMsgTarget = form.getEl();
form.getForm().waitMsg = 'Sending...';
```

and for completeness remove these 2 line from the view (you have `waitMsgTarget` in there twice):

```
waitMsgTarget: true,
waitMsg: 'Sending...',
```

---

**NOTE**: To define the `waitMsgTarget` to something other than the form itself you must pass in the **id** of the target.

For example, in your view (ie form definition) you would want to change `waitMsgTarget: true` to:

```
waitMsgTarget: 'myWindowID', 
//where myWindowID is the id of the container you want to mask
```

For reference, see:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit and
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic

Comment: This solves my initial problem, but I still don't understand how to block form's parent window, not entire viewport? I moved waitMsgTarget: true, outside of form definition, and now it blocks entire viewport.

Comment: One more issue: my submit and cancel buttons disappear on success/failure :(

Comment: waitMsgTarget:true will mask the actual form.  You don't need to move where you place it,  you need to change 'true' to a reference to the parent window. Look at the link i provided for the form.Basic,  and it will give you a description of the valid options. In other words,  waitMsgTarget isn't just a boolean value, setting it to true is just a convinient way to mask the form itself.

Comment: As far as your buttons go,  try setting them outside the init function. I have had strange things happen when i do it the way you are now. So just drop them in as a config option at the same level as autoShow etc.

Comment: Sorry to bother you this much. What would be appropriate way to set waitMsgTarget to parent window. Setting waitMsgTarget in view to this returns null, and this.up('window') blocks entire viewport.

Comment: I have added a bit to my answer underneath the "note" section.

Comment: Thanks, but. I'm giving up. I've set id: 'report' in view and form.submit({
             waitMsgTarget: 'report',
      waitMsg: 'Sending...',
             ...
in controller, but it masks entire viewport

Comment: Don't give up. I figured out the problem. My edit above was incorrect, I apologize for that. I have fixed it in the answer, but just so you know the line for waitMsgTarget in the controller is incorrect. Instead leave waitMsgTarget in the view (in the form definition) as waitMsgTarget: 'report'. I have tested this and it works.

Comment: Finally! :) Thanks a ton. Is there a way to avoid hard coding id in view?

Comment: Yeah actually, change the line in your original code from `form.getForm().waitMsgTarget = form.getEl();`
TO `form.getForm().waitMsgTarget = 'report';`

Comment: Not that, is there a way to drop out "id: report" from view definition and to reference it by something else? Because I might happen to have multiple open extjs windows with id 'report' which is not very good, as I understand.

Comment: No. Not if you want to reference the window. waitMsgTarget only accepts true, or the id of another window / component (it's stated clearly in the docs). Oh, and don't forget that little check mark by my answer :)